# Pause, Increase & Decrease Interval

Tags: javascript, html, timer, intervals

I am currently writing a code to create a slideshow. My pause button works one time around but once it starts playing again and then doesn't pause again. & same thing once i press the increase button. decrease button doesn't work. I have tried anything. Can someone point me in the right direction or let me know what is wrong. http://jsfiddle.net/#&togetherjs=7F7KQf0TtS

```
var pic= new Array();
var pcount= 0; 
var pindex = 0;
var ptimer;

var cap= new Array();
var ccount= 0; 
var cindex = 0;
var ctimer;


var resetButton = document.getElementbyId('resetButton');
resetButton.onclick= reloadPage;

function getallpics(){
    var size = prompt("How many pictures are you uploading?");
    for (var i = 0; i<size; i++) {
        pic[i] = prompt("Enter picture filename:");
        pindex++;
        cap[i] = prompt("Enter caption:");
        cindex++;
    }
}

function getpics() {
        pcount++;
        if (pcount > pindex) {
            pcount = 1;
        }
        document.getElementById("pictures").innerHTML= "<img src=" +pic[pcount-1]+ ">";
}

function getcaps(){
    ccount++;
    if(ccount > cindex){
        ccount=1;
    }
    document.getElementById("captions").innerHTML = cap[ccount-1];
}

function displaypics() {
    ptimer = setInterval("getpics()", 3000);
    ctimer = setInterval("getcaps()", 3000);
}

function pause(){
    clearTimeout(ptimer);
    clearTimeout(ctimer);
}

function increase() {
   ptimer = setInterval("getpics()", 1000);
   ctimer = setInterval("getcaps()", 1000);
}


function decrease() {
   ptimer = setInterval("getpics()", 6000);
   ctimer = setInterval("getcaps()", 6000);
}

function reloadPage(){
   window.location.reload();
}
```

Comment: a codepen or jsfiddle would also really help so people dont have to guess blindly and fix only what sticks out to them

Comment: @Todd thanks. ive never used jsfiddle. Im new to this since i'm in college. I added the link.

Comment: Posting code here is preferred, links don't necessarily last as long as your post here. Code should be trimmed to the minimum required to demonstrate the issue, which often leads to a fix before posting. Putting code elsewhere tends to have the opposite effect.